# Angular Service Observable doesnt trigger components subscription second time

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to subscribe component to Service Subject to make sure the component subscription run on service emittion.

The problem is subscription hits only first time after that the subscription doesnt hit also the observable return 0 subscription attached second time.

Following is the code:

```
export class StoreService {
    private storesList : Subject<Array<KeyValue<string>>> = null;

    constructor(private http: Http, private _uService: UserService) {
        this.storesList = new Subject<Array<KeyValue<string>>>();
     }
    loadStores(): void{
        this.getAllStores().subscribe(m=>{
            debugger;
            this.storesList.next(m);
        });
    }
    storeListEvent(): Observable<Array<KeyValue<string>>>{
    return this.storesList.asObservable();
    } 
}
```

While the component is.

```
export class HeaderNavComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit,OnDestroy  {

    private storeUpdateSubscription = null;    
    constructor(private _userService: UserService, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private _storeService: StoreService, private router: Router, private location: Location) {

        this.storeUpdateSubscription = this._storeService.storeListEvent().subscribe(stores => {
            debugger;
            this.appStore = stores;
            this.verifySuperAdmin();
        });
    }
```

**Aim to call that the above subscription in component every time**

When Store Service - `loadStores` is called

Comment: Consider using `new ReplaySubject<Array<KeyValue<string>>>(1)` to keep the last value until `loadStores()` provides the `next` value. This way, new subscribers will always get a value.

Comment: you are not destroying component and service anywhere  right ?

Comment: can you provide code at stackbiz

Comment: @PranayRana yes i am not destroying the component and service too. Component is in the Header Part of the application which will always stay there.

Comment: can you provide code here : https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Where do you call `loadStores` exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are applying an **antipattern**: NEVER subscribe a service call in the same service. You have to return the call and the component have to subscribe to this Observable.

Any way, since the storeList is a subject, you can simplify doing that:

```
this.getAllStores().subscribe(this.storesList);
```

because a subject is an observer aswell

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not complete (e.g. there is no `getAllStores()` or `storeListEvent()` method, it is not clear what `userService`does) so what I am going to say may be not correct in your case.

Anyways, the thing I recommend you to do is simplify your logic along these lines

1. Remove the Subject from StoreService
2. make `loadStores()` method return an Observable
3. In `HeaderNavComponent` subscribe to the Observable returned by
   `loadStores()`
4. Place the subscription logic in the `ngOnInit()` method rather than
   in the constructor

This is how the code could look like

```
    export class StoreService {

        constructor(private http: Http, private _uService: UserService) {
         }
        loadStores(): Observable<Array<KeyValue<string>>> {
               return this.getAllStores();
        }
    }



    export class HeaderNavComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit,OnDestroy  {

        private storeUpdateSubscription = null;    
        constructor(private _userService: UserService, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private _storeService: StoreService, private router: Router, private location: Location) {}


      ngOnInit() {
            this.storeUpdateSubscription = this._storeService.subscribe(stores => {
                debugger;
                this.appStore = stores;
                this.verifySuperAdmin();
            });
        }
}
```

**ADDITIONAL COMMENTS**

I assume that the method `getAllStores()` of `StoreService` performs an http call via the `Http` service you define in the constructor

Looking at your code `getAllStores()` return an Observable, otherwise you would not be able to `subscribe`

If this is correct, rather than subscribe to `getAllStores()` returned Observable just to emit a new value with another Observable (`storesList`)  which `HeaderNavComponent` subscribes to, you can simply have `HeaderNavComponent` subscribe to the Observable returned by `getAllStores()` method

I hope this is more clear now

Comment: I have updated the code with storeListEvent() function, What i want to to run the subscription of the component every time load Store of service is called. i am confused with `this._storeService.subscribe` can you please explain

Comment: I have edited my response with some more comments. I hope this is more clear now and that it helps

Comment: As far i have understood by `HeaderNavComponent subscribe to the Observable returned by getAllStores() method` - you mean use subscription in component from the observable, will its subscription will hit every time i call `getAllStores` from other component. as i want to update the header component with the list updated every time any component calls that service.

Comment: No. If there are more components firing the `loadAllStores()` method and you want the `HeaderNavComponent` to be updated any time the `loadAllStores()` method is executed, then YOUR CODE SHOULD WORK. Are you sure you are not unsubscribing the `storeUpdateSubscription` somewhere between the first and the subsequent calls?

Comment: no i am not unsubscribing it anywhere, it works first time, on second time when i see subject subscribers - it shows empty subscription.

Comment: No idea then. Sorry I can not help more

Answer (score 1):

The first I would do here is to call the `this.storeList.next(m);` not inside another subscription but directly from your function. If that works, then you know that the problem is with your other subscription, not with `storesList`.

Comment: actually when `this.storesList.next(m);` hits second time, it always get empty subscribers - as first time while calling next it have one subscriber